# Do I need to apply permit before going hiking in Grand Canyon?

Tags: usa, national-parks, permits, grand-canyon

I am planning to go to Grand Canyon in December, around Christmas time. I want to go Bright Angel Trail, which needs camping in the wild. I searched on [this website](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/backcountry-permit.htm) that I don't need to apply permit early. There is one choice is that "*These permits are issued in person only, are for one or two consecutive nights, and cannot be purchased more than one day prior to the start of a hike.*" But someone said that I have to apply online. So I am wondering whether I have to apply earlier or not. (Online application process seems very inconvenient.)

BTW, I have no car, is it convenient to go to trail entrance by public (commercial) transportation?

**EDIT**: *Nov 21, 2:08*

I have no winter hiking experience, actually this will be my first time hiking, and that's the main reason I choose Grand Canyon which is south side of US and everyone said it is not too difficult, but now I know it also could be very cold in winter. So I booked a *Bright Angel Lodge Reservation* online just now, so I am not going to camp inside the part, I think I will get into trouble to camp in winter without enough experience.

I have been searched for all kinds of information including transportation and lodges online for hours. I also booked a round flight from **Pittsburgh** to **FLG**, but it arrives FLG at 9pm, which is too late to catch the last shuttle to Grand Canyon. Is it possible to camp somewhere around the airport? or I must book a hotel in airport? I will arrive FLG in 21 Dec, the *Bright Angel Lodge Reservation* is on 22 Dec night.

Comment: That is the official website.

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: If you are not an experienced hiker, you stand _no chance_ to make a trip down into Grand Canyon and back out, even in two days. This is very strenuous, and every year _experienced_ hikers die on it.

Comment: You realize it is the middle of winter?

Comment: @Aganju Thank you for your advice. I cancelled my plan. And I asked for some advices [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82992/advices-for-hiking-in-sedona-and-grand-canyon) for my winter hiking in AZ, can you give me some advices for my hiking plan? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need a permit, and per the last [Space Availability Report](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/upload/CorAvail.pdf), Bright Angel is booked immediately after Christmas, but there may still be availability (the report is from a few weeks ago) earlier in the month. If you cannot get a permit, it's possible to try to for a last-minute permit in person (show up early) or the waitlist; details are on [the website you linked](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/backcountry-permit.htm).

I would apply immediately by fax (you can use an online service to send the fax from your computer if you don't have easy access to a fax machine) and they'll respond by email.

I don't know your winter hiking experience, but ensure you are prepared for [the conditions](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/winter-recreation.htm), which may include considerable amounts of ice and snow on the trail, winter storms, and water not being available during the off-season in some areas. Make sure you have the necessary equipment.

[This page](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/gettingaround.htm) has some information on transportation that may be helpful, but we don't know where you're coming from. That page recommends outfits offering both scheduled and on-demand transportation services and taxis. Without a car, careful planning will be required to avoid becoming stranded, especially in winter.

Comment: Wow, so much thanks for your detailed reply, I have not enough reputation to vote up your answer, but thank you very much. I have no winter hiking experience, that's the main reason I choose **south-side** Grand Canyon for my hiking. I edited my question, can you give me some **hint**/**advices** for my coming trip? That may be very helpful.

Comment: @JW.ZG It sounds like you're making a very prudent choice by not doing this trip as your first time hiking. Such a hike is serious business, especially in winter. I would make your first trip a less strenuous one not during the winter, ideally not alone. You can consult [outdoors.stackexchange](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) for more advice on that, info on day hikes you can do from the lodge and what kind of gear you need. I'd [ask a new question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about transportation from Flagstaff to the lodge and where to stay on the 21st.

Comment: Hi, Zach Lipton. I really appreciate your patient answer. I have asked another question [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82992/advices-for-hiking-in-sedona-and-grand-canyon). I tried ask questions in `outdoors`, but I cannot use those key words like `Grand Canyon` or `Hiking` because of my low reputation. Thanks again for your time.